# Why the dimensions of PIL.Image.open() function object gets changed when converted to numpy array

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I am trying to read an image using the Pillow module as in the following command:

```
import PIL
import numpy as np
img = PIL.Image.open('/home/wd/foo.jpg').convert('L')
img.size
(247, 249)
```

but, when I convert it to numpy array for image processing, the dimensions get exchanged/changed.

```
img1 = np.array(img)
img1.shape
(249, 247)
```

I have tried to find the solution in the documentation, but couldn't find it.

I am using python 2.7.13, Pillow(PIL) version 5.1.0 on linux machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the PIL [documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.3.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.size):

> PIL.Image.size
>
> Image size, in pixels. The size is given as a 2-tuple (width, height).

However, `numpy.ndarray.shape` simply returns the shape in the other order (height, width)